# How to access to cisco's serial port using an usb-adapter?

Tags: usb, cisco, serial-port

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I know if my serial adapter card is working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79302/how-do-i-know-if-my-serial-adapter-card-is-working)

I should connect to a Cisco Router by serial port, someone suggested me to use an usb-adapter, I did it.
Of following, I show you the screen of the commands lsusb and dmesg

lsusb:

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 03f0:171d Hewlett-Packard Wireless (Bluetooth + WLAN) Interface [Integrated Module]
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
***Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC***
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E620 USB Modem
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ca:1810 Ricoh Co., Ltd Pavilion Webcam [R5U870]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

dmesg | grep usb

```
[10305.290155] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, address 2 
[10309.642637] usb 3-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 3
[10309.851294] usb 3-1: Detected FT232RL [10309.851299] usb 3-1: Number of endpoints 2 
[10309.851304] usb 3-1: Endpoint 1 MaxPacketSize 64 
[10309.851308] usb 3-1: Endpoint 2 MaxPacketSize 64 
[10309.851312] usb 3-1: Setting MaxPacketSize 64
[10309.852239] usb 3-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

I've installed minicom and configured it inserting /dev/ttyUSB0 as port and set the  Bps/Par/Bits with the value 9600 8N1

I've tried to connect to it but minicom doesn't work.

someone can help me????I don't want to use windows with putty!!!!
thank you in advance.