# Connecting to a Cisco router via serial

Tags: cisco

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I know if my serial adapter card is working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79302/how-do-i-know-if-my-serial-adapter-card-is-working)

I'm not quite sure if I worded the title correctly, but here's my issue:
I want to connect to a heavy duty Cisco router (not quite sure what model, but its an older one) using a USB to serial adapter on my Linux netbook. The netbook has a few USB 2.0 ports and a 10/100 Ethernet port.

I plugged the adapter in, loaded the modules for it, opened up putty, configured the baud rate, flow control, told it to use /dev/ttyUSB0, etc... pressed connect, and .......... nothing.
I found a thing saying to use "*sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0*" but that didn't do squat.
I even tried a total shot in the dark by plugging the rollover cable directly into my RJ-45 port and sending the putty connection through eth0 (though I was posative that wasn't going to work, and it didnt).

Any ideas to get my Linux book connected to the cisco routers?

Comment: Can you connect to the router from any other OS or system, using a USB-to-serial adapter?

Comment: Yeah, a fellow student connects to the same router with an adapter on his Windows 7 laptop.

Comment: Can you ask him for the settings...baud, parity, etc.?

Comment: Already did, I have all of the settings correct. It just seems to be an issue with how Linux uses at the adapter.

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/22509/how-to-access-to-ciscos-serial-port-using-an-usb-adapter?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I have used several different laptops and serial adapters to connect to Cisco devices.  I typically use `minicom` to connect -- you might try that.   It is available from the software center, or you can use `sudo apt-get install minicom`.  (If you do use minicom, use Ctrl-A and Z to access options -- check the speed and serial settings.  Everything else tends to be correct.)

And /dev/ttyUSB0 is most likely correct if you're using a USB to Serial adapter.

Rollover to RJ-45 will *not* work, as you suspected.

If things still do not work, look for a different serial adapter -- I've been through several that work fine in Linux, but I suppose it's possible you might have gotten one that needs drivers that are not easily loadable under Ubuntu/Linux.

Borrow your friend's adapter if you can, and you can rule out your adapter that way.

Comment: Got one that supports Linux kernel 2.4 and above. Run putty (or whatever terminal program you prefer) as root and BAM! it works.